# How do I instantiate structs inside a nested class?

Tags: c++, struct, nested, inner-classes

So I googled everywhere and cannot get a straight answer to my problem. I haven't touch C++ in a while so I wanted to approach a minimalist coding structure, but I ran into a problem.

I have a parent class call Data in a .h file

I have 2 more classes nested in Data called "Memory" & "Functions"

I created 2 .cpp files, one for each nested classes, "Memory.cpp" stores variable and struct data and "Functions.cpp" stores function data

I am having issues with the "Memory" class

I cannot find a way or solution to instantiate the "Memory" class's structs at all try as I might

Here is my Classes.h file

```
#pragma once
#include "main.h"

class Data
{
public:

    class Memory
    {
    public:
        //I ALREADY CODED THE STRUCTS IN MY "MEMORY.CPP" FILE
        struct sig;
        struct set;
        struct val;

        //I TRIED WRITING THIS INSIDE THIS PUBLIC CLASS MEMORY AND ITS AN ERROR
        //sig sig0;
        //set set0;
        //val val0;
    };


    class Functions
    {
    public:
        void setup(Memory& gMem);
        void mainLoop(Memory& gMem);
    };

    Memory gMem;
    Functions gFunc;
    

    Data()
    {
        //I'M TRYING TO PASS BY REFERENCE SELF gMem INTO SETUP FUNCTION, 
        //WHICH THE FUNCTION ACCESSES THE STRUCTS INSIDE 
        //THE PUBLIC MEMORY CLASS
        //BUT IT CANNOT EVEN GRANT THIS
        this->gFunc.setup(this->gMem);
        this->gFunc.mainLoop(this->gMem);
    }
};
```

Here is my main.cpp file

```
#include "main.h"

int main()
{
    Data run;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my main.h file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Classes.h"
```

I hope this is enough information to get my problem across, I don't wanna post up my "Memory.cpp" and "Functions.cpp" files, its too much information atm. Thank you anyone who is kind enough to help me.

Comment: Well it's hard to be sure based on the limited information, but I would say that the structs you defined in memory.cpp need to be moved to a header file (memory.h presumably) and that header file needs to be included in classes.h so you can use the struct definitions there. Generally anything that you want to use in more than one file in C++ need to be defined or declared in a header file.

Comment: @john OOHHH I got it, thanks for that, so .cpp file cannot define/declare variables.

Comment: Now you are confusing me, first you said 'structs' now you are saying 'variables' Those are not the same thing. It's perfectly OK to **define** variables in cpp files (in fact that is what you should do) but if you also want to use those variables in another file then you must also **declare** them in a header file. This requires that you understand the difference between definition and declaration, which I'm wondering whether you do.

Comment: Sorry bout that @john I think I got it solved now, thank you.

Comment: I guess you need  a **PIMPL** design. The object also seems to be immovable, which is a hint to use `std::unique_ptr` along with PIMPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class members need to be complete types, if the type is incomplete you can only use a pointer or a reference to it.

So you either need to move the definitions of `sig`, `set` and `val` into the header file or turn `sig0`, `set0` and `val0` into references (use with caution, reference members have pitfalls) or (preferably smart) pointers.

Answer (score 0):

When instantiating from a struct, the struct definition must precede the instantiation in the visible or same scope as the type you're instantiating from has to be complete.

Thus the straight forward solution is to move the definitions of sig, set, and val from the .cpp file to the header file. Another solution is to declare sig0, set0, and val0 as pointers to the corresponding structs and allocate memory for them with `new` in the cpp file.